# strange cors issue with socket io

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, express, cors

I'm using btford.socket-io, and try to talk with node.

**It was working fine** but not after I change from localhost:5000 to example.org like below :

```
.factory('socket',function(socketFactory){
     //working
     var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
     //not working
     var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://example.org:5000');

      mySocket = socketFactory({
        ioSocket: myIoSocket
      });

    return mySocket;
})
```

I got this error in my console

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LIGH5VO. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
:8100/#/app/completed:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LIGH7BS. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

I also tried to set `cors({origin:"*"})` using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) npm in my express but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It s about this `A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true.`

Set allow origin to a fixed domain will fix this isssue, currently, if i i don t mistake, `http://example.org:5000`. I believe you should include the port number.

What i don t clearly understand is why you have the header credentials On.

Comment: where at where? I can't set as my request from client is mobile apps, don't have any domain.

Comment: I already set http://example.org:5000 in my socket cilent. what do you mean include port number?

Comment: cors() <-- this is used to be put in example.org which is my node server.